# combine two fields & bold one in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

want to combine two database field having datatype string.from that two fields first one make bold.
e.g.-**EmployeeName**(with Font Bold)+Address(with regular font).
i am using VS 2008 in build crystal report.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: please answer to the question i have correctedd it to understand well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below:

Take a formula and write below code:

```
"<b>"+EmployeeName+"</b>" + Address
```

Then go to the `format field` of the formula and then to `paragraph tab` there change the `text representation` to `HTML Text`